# DB2 extract data between two delimiters

Tags: db2, substr

Here is the string I am trying to extract from:
'cn=xyxyxyxyxyx  ousy,ou=information services,ou=domain users,dc=corp,dc=xyxyxx,dc=com'

I am trying to extract the string between the first 'ou=' and the second comma. In this case that is
'information services'

Here is what I have so far:
SUBSTR(F_DN, locate('ou=', F_DN)+3, locate(',', F_DN, locate(',', F_DN)+1)+1 ) as role
And this is the result:
'information services,ou=domain users,dc=co'

It seems to locate to the first character just fine but I cannot get the length correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select regexp_substr(str, 'ou=([^,]+)', 1, 1, '', 1)
from (values 'cn=xyxyxyxyxyx ousy,ou=information services,ou=domain users,dc=corp,dc=xyxyxx,dc=com') t (str);
```

Comment: Awesome, that works. Thank you so much. I am not familiar with regexp_substr. I'll have to play with that some more. Thanks.